# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'aetos.it.teithe.gr' (111)

Tags: mysql

i would like to connect to mysql server of my technological institute..
my php files
db_config.php

```
<?php
 /*
 All Database connection variables
 */
define("DB_SERVER", "aetos.it.teithe.gr");
define("DB_DATABASE", "votingdb");
define("DB_USER", "root@localhost");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "..");

?>
```

db_connect.php

```
   <?php

  /*
 A class file to connect to database
 */
 class DB_CONNECT{

  /*
  function to connect with database
  */
  function connect(){
   //import database connection variables
   require_once __DIR__ . "/db_config.php";

   //connecting to mysql database
   $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or    die (mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL);

//returning connection cursor
if (!is_null($con)){
    return $con;
   }
  }

}
```

test_connection.php

```
<?php

  /*
    get firm(table) from votingdb database details(firm_name, email, ...)
  */

//array for json response
$response = array();

//include db_connect class
require_once __DIR__ . "/db_connect.php";

 //initialise DB_CONNECT class
 $db_connect = new DB_CONNECT();

 //get $link for the db connection link
 $link = $db_connect->connect();

 //get firm_name field from firm table
 $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT firm_name, city FROM Firm");

 if (!empty($result)){
   echo nl2br("firm has " . mysqli_num_rows($result) . " firms\n");

  $response["firms"] = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //temp user array
    $firm = array();
    $firm["firm name"] = $row["firm_name"];
    $firm["firm city"] = $row["city"];

    //push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["firms"], $firm);
  }

  //success
  $response["success"] = 1;

  //echo json response
  echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

  //free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  //close connection
  mysqli_close($link);
}
 else {
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "No firms found";

   echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  }


 ?>
```

when i run test_connection.php i get the following error...Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'aetos.it.teithe.gr' (111) in /home/student/x0809/tsironis/public_html/Ptixiaki/db_connect.php on line 16 2003
can anyone explain what i am doing wrong?

i also add my.cnf file

```
   [client]
   socket=/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/run/mysql.sock

   [mysqld_safe]
   socket=/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/run/mysql.sock

   [mysqld]
   socket=/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/run/mysql.sock
   pid-file=/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/run/mysql.pid
   log=/dev/null
   log-error=//home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/log/mysql.log
   log_bin=/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/log/mysql-bin.log
   datadir=/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/data
   tmpdir=/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/tmp

  max_binlog_size=10M
  skip-networking
```

Comment: first thing i see thats the user is wrong not 
define("DB_USER", "root@localhost"); only 
define("DB_USER", "root");

Comment: second is: it looks like that the database is not reach on port 3306. is there a firewall or in my.cnf the bind address is localhost. change it to 0.0.0.0

Comment: still the same..i have also changed the path to server...("DB_SERVER", "aetos.it.teithe.gr/home/student/x0809/tsironis/mysql/run/mysql.sock");

Answer (score 1):

sorry, this is not the Answer, but i cant format it,
i have checked the Port from here. Port 3306 is **NOT** open, so you cant reach the DB. So you only can get it via a tunnel on ssh

```
$ nmap aetos.it.teithe.gr

Starting Nmap 5.20 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-13 19:14 CEST
Nmap scan report for aetos.it.teithe.gr (195.251.123.232)
Host is up (0.083s latency).
Not shown: 985 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
53/tcp   open     domain
80/tcp   open     http
110/tcp  open     pop3
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
143/tcp  open     imap
443/tcp  open     https
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
993/tcp  open     imaps
995/tcp  open     pop3s
4444/tcp filtered krb524
5432/tcp open     postgresql
6667/tcp open     irc
6969/tcp open     acmsoda
```

Comment: i am a very begginer to all of this...can you describe in detail how can i get it via a tunnel on ssh..

Comment: short question: do you use linux on your db server and client server

Comment: sh...., Windows is not my favorite System, but i have found a page where mysql it decribe

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-and-ssh.html

let me now if it helps

Comment: the only thing is: with ssh you make a secure connection to you remote server (DB) and then you can forward a local port. so it is possible to connect to localhost ie. port 3307 and it goes directly to the remote machine to port 3306 (DB) and you can connect as local user. it is then the same as you connect direcly on db db machine

Comment: finally...Bernd Buffen what i want to establish is not a remote connection to the mysql server...my current working directory is located inside the same server...any other suggestions for what may be wrong?

Comment: path to mysqli socket is.../var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock..do i have to make any changes to my.cnf file?

Comment: @tsiro in your defines you use a public Address. Test to use the inernal local IP or name to connect -** define("DB_SERVER", "aetos.it.teithe.gr");**